# iOS cellForItemAtIndexPath beyond the Array bound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

A question about UICollectionView. UICollectionView nested in UITableViewCell. The problem is the following simple code, but online `[self.imageInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` here often appear array beyond bound, very strange!! IndexPath bound is not above the `collectionView: (UICollectionView *) collectionView numberOfItemsInSection: (NSInteger) section` this function constraints, why the array beyond bound.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imageInfos.count;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LKMImageInfo *imageInfo = [self.imageInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return imageCell;
}
```

Comment: add more information with UITableviewcell code.

Comment: i use xib, and the layout is not complex

Comment: Check count of `self.feed.blog.imageInfos` & `self.imageInfos`

Comment: Are you using the collectionView in the every tableViewCell ? and getting the array bound issue.

Comment: @Aashish1aug yeah~ so strange~

Comment: @dahiya_boy oh~ Sorry for my typo error，you can think `self.feed.blog.imageInfos` as self.imageInfos

Comment: I did't get ur issues please can u elaborate. I already implemented collection view in table view cell. where u r getting issue.?

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR the online app crash , i find this `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] ` in crash log and it locate `LKMImageInfo *imageInfo = [self.imageInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` this line.

Comment: @acumen I think you are reloading the collectionView in the CellForRowatIndexPath method of tableView. I will be better understand your problem if you can add the code of CellForRow of your tableviewcell.

Comment: @Aashish1aug sorry, i can't offer more code beacuse of project privacy, 
wait a moment~ i try my best to offer more code

Comment: @acumen u r reloading ur collection view    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {.      u need to reload the collection view after successfully download the data from ur url.

Comment: at which line stop your code ?

Comment: @acumen It's ok, For now I will suggest you to debug or recheck you code in cellForRow method and check with a hard code values array in collectionView and then try to fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your UICollectionView item represents `LKMImageInfo` object. So instead of fetching `LKMImageInfo` object from `indexPath.row`, you should fetch it from `indexPath.item`. Like below:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imageInfos.count;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LKMImageInfo *imageInfo = [self.imageInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return imageCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom table view cell and inside add collection view. Write collection view delegates in the custom class of table view cell.